# React/Redux What should i use as state, props, helpers

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, store, reducers

i'm a bit confused with state and redux use case, is there any 'best way of thinking' about that kind of things.

Here is an exemple:

```
this.state = {
  url: this.switch(location.pathname),
};

//listen on url change
history.listen((location, action) => {
  //set url
  this.setState({
    url: this.switch(history.location.pathname),
  });
});
```

history came from an external file (as an helper):

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Render :

```
<Dialog message={this.state.url}/>
```

I'm wondering about is url should be in my Redux store ? Or should it stay as a state ?

If anyone have links, ideas or any thoughts on the topics, since i have no idea what should be in redux and what should stay only in my component.

NB: I know i have no need of redux in this example, but i'm trying to understand the idea behind it.

Comment: I believe this might not be a good question for StackOverflow, as there is no Right™ way of thinking and answers will end up being based on opinions. However, here are some resources you might find useful https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367, https://hackernoon.com/avoiding-accidental-complexity-when-structuring-your-app-state-6e6d22ad5e2a, https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

Comment: ...or neither? Why are you storing the location you get from react-router in the state or redux at all? Just read it from routing